# How to get subscriptions history from Google Play Subscription API?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Is there is a way to access subscriptions history at Google Play? How to prevent loosing of fact that user have already purchased subscription in the case if app crashes at the moment of storing purchaseToken for example? (before sending it to my backend for verification)

Answer (score -2):

try getSkuDetails() method, just change type to "subs"

[more info](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getSkuDetails)

Comment: why do you think it might help? method's description says nothing about purchases history...